# Badly placed ()'s error

Tags: c++, sql, c

Hello I'm using c++ with embedded SQL trying to receive command line arguments as SQL statements.

For instance I want to be able to do: `./a.out proceedings(foo#bar)` and tokenize the argument into: `proceedings`, `foo`, and `bar` with `#`, `(`, and `)` as delimiters.

Anyways, I was just wondering if there is a way to use brackets in the argument because I receive `Badly placed ()'s` as an error.

Answer (score 6):

Nevermind, I've learned that I can use quotation marks in the command line which wont give me the error.